# JavaFx : tab item does not fill the content

Tags: javafx, tabs

I have a `TabPane` declared like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>

<TabPane fx:id="rootNode" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" stylesheets="@dark_theme.css" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.AppController" />
```

And I want to add tabs from my controller. So I do :

```
    jsonConfig.getAvailableChannelIds().forEach( chId -> {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("tab_item.fxml"));
            Tab item = fxmlLoader.load();
            item.setText(String.format("%d", chId));
            rootNode.getTabs().add(item);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

"tab_item.fxml" looks as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<Tab xmlns:fx="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <VBox>
         <fx:include source="test.fxml"/>
   </VBox>
</Tab>
```

And finally "test.fxml" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
```

And here is what I have :

[image]

What am I missing to fill the `Tab` content with the red square ?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: My guess is that the `AnchorPane` in `test.fxml` needs `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` set to `Infinity`.

Comment: You explicitly set the preferred size to 600x400. What do you expect to happen/

Comment: Unrelated: this `xmlns:fx="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` is not the namespace for FXML.  The XML namespace you provided is for [XSL transforms](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp), which isn't what your document is using at all.  Instead use `xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"`.  The namespace, in this case, is only important for XML validation (which you aren't using) and for helping tools, such as IDEs, provide better editing assistance.

Comment: @SedJ601 unfortunately, having this <AnchorPane maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" style="-fx-background-color: red;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" /> leads to no item displayed on the scene. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get rid of `prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"` as suggested by @James_D?

Comment: @SedJ601 yes, I got rid of it - but the key point here is to have AnchorPane as a content for Tab. With VBox approach as used originally deleting prefs leads to no item rendered

Comment: If you also get rid of the min and max sizes, so the anchor pane is allowed to grow, you can then tell the `VBox` to make the anchor pane in `test.fxml` to grow as large as it likes, using the usual `VBox` settings. I don't really understand why you have the `VBox` there at all, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most layout panes, such as `VBox`, will by default try to size their content to the preferred size, and will make every attempt to keep the sizes within the constraints specified as the minimum and maximum.

I recommend reading the old Oracle [layout tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/jfxpub-layout.htm). It was written a long time ago (before Java 8), so the code style is a bit out of date, but the layout concepts are all still relevant. Also read the Javadocs for the [layout package](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html), and presumably you already read the Javadocs for any layout component you are using (if not, you should always read the docs for the classes you use).

You have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" 
            minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" 
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
            style="-fx-background-color: red;"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" 
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
```

which explicitly sets the preferred size to 600x400 pixels, and additionally sets the minimum and maximum sizes to `-Infinity`, which is the sentinel value [`Region.USE_PREF_SIZE`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/constant-values.html#javafx.scene.layout.Region.USE_PREF_SIZE). Therefore, the `VBox` will always size the content to 600x400 pixels (as long as there is enough space in the `VBox`to do so).

Remove all those settings (I corrected the namespace too, though you don't really need it here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: red;"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" />
```

Now the `VBox` will still attempt to set the content to its preferred size, which by default is computed from its own content. Since the anchor pane is empty, that preferred size will be computed as 0x0. However, since the max size is now unconstrained, you can tell the `VBox` to let it grow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<Tab xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/">
        <VBox fillWidth="true">
        <fx:include source="test.fxml" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
        </VBox>
</Tab>
```

Now the content defined in `test.fxml` will fill the `VBox`. The behavior of a `Tab` is to let its content fill the entire region of the tab, so the `VBox` will fill the tab.

Of course, it's not really clear why you are wrapping `test.fxml` in a `VBox` in the first place. Since the tab will be filled by its content by default, why not just simplify to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>

<Tab xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/">
        <fx:include source="test.fxml" />
</Tab>
```

Here is a complete example, with all the unnecessary hard-coded sizes and redundant layout panes removed:

`HelloApplication.java`:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.tab;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

`hello-view.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>

<TabPane fx:id="rootNode"
         tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE"
         xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/"
         fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.tab.AppController" />
```

`AppController.java`:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.tab;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

public class AppController {

    @FXML
    private TabPane rootNode ;

    public void initialize() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("tab_item.fxml"));
            Tab item = fxmlLoader.load();
            item.setText(String.format("%d", 42));
            rootNode.getTabs().add(item);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`tab-item.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>

<Tab xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/">
        <fx:include source="test.fxml" />
</Tab>
```

and `test.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: red;"/>
```

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation and for the doc links - now I've got the picture

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so I found at least a workaround here -> just wrap fx:include with AnchorsPane and it works :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<Tab xmlns:fx="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <content>
       <AnchorPane>
            <fx:include source="test.fxml" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0"/>
       </AnchorPane>
   </content>
</Tab>
```

Comment: Your solution to having explicitly set the pref size to something you don't want is to find a workaround that forces the pref size to be ignored????

Comment: @James_D and what is your suggestion besides being a bit arrogant in your comment? If I'm wrong somewhere could you please specify it directly if possible ?

Comment: Don’t explicitly set the preferred size.

Comment: @James_D it's not enough as I see, if I stay with VBox I see nothing rendered at all. So the key point here is to use AnchorPane as a content for Tab item

Comment: You also have the max size explicitly set to `USE_PREF_SIZE` (`-Infinity`). Get rid of all those, and you can use layout settings in the natural way. Why do you need to wrap the tab's content in a pane anyway?